# Containing markup INSIDE data

Tags: html

Yes, I am struggling with displaying data from our database that CONTAINS markup! One particular field I am displaying has an open-bold tag but no close bold tag. I am trying to 'contain' this markup so it doesn't affect the rest of the page.

The data coming from my database is like this text:

```
this is soem nasty <b>data
```

(note the lack of a closing < /b > tag)

If I enclose the markup in a div, the rest of the page is bold:

```
<div>this is some nasty <b>data</div>
```

However if I wrap it in a table like this:

```
<table><tr><td>this is some nasty <b>data</td></tr></table>
```

All is well! In fact, the DOM inspector for both FF (FireBug) and IE9 show the tree. In the div-case, it shows the open-b tag and the rest of the document contained within it. But the table seems to enclose it.

How can I get this to 'close the b' without a table?

Comment: Assuming that you are determining the markup isn't malicious by some either means, and that this is an ongoing problem with multiple tags, I would probably run the data through a parser that attempts to restructure the markup.

Comment: Are you displaying the markup in text format or are you inserting the markup inside the page?

Comment: This is early-days for our data team populating catalog product descriptions. They've used HTML markup in the descriptions themselves and aren't very good about proper format. It's bad enough that they've been allowed to do this at all, but the markup is bogus. Not dangerous, but mal-formed at times. We're looking at mark-down and other schemes to accomodate what they legitmately need to do but touching all the 'older' descriptions would be a huge deal.

Answer (score 1):

You use a closing `</b>` tag properly, like any sane human being.

You can use `DOMDocument` and `tidy` to try and fix the malformed markup in case you have no control over it, but it's best if you could fix it before it got to your database.

Answer (score 0):

I've read somewhere that [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) should be able to achieve this. Might be worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

I took a cue from HTML rich-text editors like TinyMCE and built up an IFrame. It seems to contain the arbitrary, possibly-mal-formed content better.